# Am I using JPA API or Hibernate API?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a doubt related to the following example:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    // Factory per la creazione delle sessioni di Hibernate:
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // CREATE CRUD Operation:
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Integer addPerson(Person p) {

        System.out.println("Inside addPerson()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer personID = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            personID = (Integer) session.save(p);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return personID;

    }

    // READ CRUD Operation (legge un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
    public Person getById(int id) {

        System.out.println("Inside getById()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;          
        Person retrievedPerson = null;  

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            retrievedPerson = (Person) session.get(Person.class, id);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {                 
            session.close();
        }

        return retrievedPerson;
    }

    // READ CRUD Operation (recupera la lista di tutti i record nella tabella):
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getPersonsList() {

        System.out.println("Inside getPersonsList()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Person> personList = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
            personList = criteria.list();
            System.out.println("personList: " + personList);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return personList;
    }

    // DELETE CRUD Operation (elimina un singolo record avente uno specifico id):
    public void delete(int id) {

        System.out.println("Inside delete()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Person personToDelete = getById(id);
            session.delete(personToDelete);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Person personToUpdate) {

        System.out.println("Inside update()");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Insite update() method try");
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(personToUpdate);

            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) { 
            if (tx != null)                 
                tx.rollback();          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }   

    }


}
```

In this example am I using JPA API or Hibernate API...The used annotation belong to JPA or to Hibernate?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 6):

The import makes it clear: neither.

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

This is a Spring annotation that works with either Hibernate or JPA.  The JTA API is independent of the ORM solution you choose.

The rest of your imports all refer to Hibernate.

I can understand your confusion: JPA is an API that is independent of the ORM solution you choose.  Hibernate is one implementation.

Comment: EJB3.1 isn't an "implementation" of JPA, it's a spec

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb:

- SessionFactory --> Hibernate
- EntityManager --> JPA

`@Transactional` belongs to Spring. And works with JPA and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only import from `org.hibernate`, you are obviously using Hibernate.